# Media player plays after service is destroyed

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a bound service that I want to stop through a notification click.

In my main_activity I do this onDestroy to unbind my service:

```
public void onDestroy(){ 
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mediaPlayerBound){
                 System.out.println(mediaPlayerBound);
                 unbindService(mServCon);
                 mMediaPlayerServiceBound = false;
        }
```

This part works fine as I get that mediaPlayerBound is true and so the service is getting unbound.

Then in my service:
I call the following after receiving a broadcast.

```
stopForeground(true);
stopSelf();
```

Lastly:

in OnDestroy within the service I use:

```
public void onDestroy(){
    this.unregisterReceiver(nextBroadCast);
    System.out.println("Stopped Service");
    }
```

Now my question is, I started playing a song with the mediaPlayer but it persists even after I have gotten confirmation that that the service has reached onDestroy. What do I do to stop it from playing as soon as I call stopSelf(); ?

Answer (score 1):

In service I read it somewhere that you will not always watch onDestroyed has been called. There are many terms and condition. but as you said you are receiving this event then try the below code. but I am guessing you are able to get your media player instance in it. so here is a workaround

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();
this.unregisterReceiver(nextBroadCast);
yourMediaPlayer= MediaPlayer.create(x.this,R.raw.sound);
if(yourMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
  yourMediaPlayer.stop();
  yourMediaPlayer.release();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your service file . `onTaskRemoved` is  call when your app is closing.so it stop service

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
 if(player.isPlaying())
 {
    player.stop();
 } 

    player.release();

    stopSelf();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
 if(player.isPlaying())
 {
    player.stop();
 }

    player.release();
    stopSelf();

}
```

And in Your Activity place code when you want stop runing service .

```
    Intent i=new Intent(this, MediaSongServiece.class);
    stopService(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

A short note is that if you used MediaPlayer to play music, you would stop MediaPlayer.

**Put this source in Destroy().**

```
private void stopPlay() {
   this.unregisterReceiver(nextBroadCast);
   if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}
```